# It has been done, but it shouldn't have - is this ok?

Tags: grammar

Correct (but weird) would be "It has been done, but it shouldn't have been done"

First I shortened it to: 
"It has been done, but it shouldn't have" - my intuition is saying it should be okay. But a colleague planted a seed of doubt, by asking, if it shouldn't rather go: 
"It has been done, but it shouldn't have been"

Is my version ok? Or should it be like "It has been done, but it shouldn't"?

I think I base my intuition on the phrase when you receive an unexpected gift you can say "aaah, you shouldn't have!"

(if you can also point to a resource, where this grammar thing is covered, maybe some murphy's grammar in use page or sth, that would be great)

Comment: Of the three, "It has been done, but it shouldn't have been" sounds the most natural to me

Comment: As an American, I think *"... it shouldn't have"* is ungrammatical in American English. I have seen shortenings something like this in British English, but you'd have to ask somebody from the U.K. whether it's grammatical there.

Comment: @Peter Shor, could you please elaborate the correct options for American English?

Comment: The most common thing to say would be *"but it shouldn't have been."* You could expand it to *"... shouldn't have been done,"* but most people wouldn't. We generally keep all the auxiliary verbs, so *"you shouldn't have"* for an unexpected gift is fine, as you're just leaving off an implicit main verb, but *"it shouldn't have"* is incorrect when the full expansion is *"it shouldn't have been done."*

Comment: @PeterShor et al., *It has been done, but it shouldn't have been* sounds fine to me (American English)

Comment: You left out several other ways of phrasing that, including *It has, but (it) should not have been done* which would be my own preference.

Peter, why might *it shouldn't have* be ungrammatical in any variety of English, please? If *it shouldn't have* is ungrammatical by itself, how did it become acceptable in *but it shouldn't have been*?

Either way, did you notice that in the Question, *it shouldn't have* doesn’t appear by itself?

Clare, don’t you think in *It has been done, but it shouldn't have been* either *have* or *been* or both are redundant?

Comment: @PeterShor I agree about keeping the modals, but I think there may be a difference in some cases.  'Although carpeting has been done, it shouldn't have' means it got done too soon, as in I've not finished painting in there yet. Whereas 'although carpeting has been done, it shouldn't have been' implies that it was a mistake, that the area wasn't supposed to get carpet at all. But I might ought not to have been commenting here because I use modals oddly.